# Laravel 5.2 upload image to storage

Tags: laravel, file-upload, upload, laravel-5

I want to ask, how can I make that somebody selects an image, then he clicks upload and the image will save into my project (example: project/public/images). Thank you :)

Comment: What have you tried? Show some of your efforts, how many links on Google you have opened and what you didn't understand there. This is a very simple and general task and you should get this by simple Google search.

Comment: I have tried a lot of things, but still nothing works, and I have visited at least 50 forums, articles and questions about this, but mostly there are tutorials about how to save image to db

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just do:

```
$file = $request->file('image');
$name = $file->getClientOriginalName();
$path = public_path("images/$name");

Storage::put($path, File::get($file->getRealPath()));
```

However. I would recommend to use laravel medialibrary package:

https://docs.spatie.be/laravel-medialibrary/v4/introduction

This way you can just do:

```
$post->addMediaFromRequest('image')->toCollection('images');
```

Comment: Thank you for recommentation :)

Answer (score 0):

Or else you can do like this

```
    $destinationPath = '';
    $filename        = '';

    if (Input::hasFile('file')) {
        $file            = Input::file('file');
        $destinationPath = public_path().'/images/';
        $filename        = time() . '_' . $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $filename = str_replace(' ','_',$filename);
        $uploadSuccess   = $file->move($destinationPath, $filename);
    }
```